# How to automatically convert from Array of Classes to Class of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, class

I would like to know how (if it is possible) could I program a Java class using a data layout `Array of Class`, for example:

```
public class X{

     double a;
     double b;
     double c;
}

public X array_of_x[SIZE] = new X [SIZE];
```

but internally the data would be store as a layout of `Class of Arrays` like this:

```
 public class X{

     double a[] = new double [SIZE];
     double b[] = new double [SIZE];
     double c[] = new double [SIZE];
}

public X class_x = new X();
```

My objective is that the programmer could programed in a more intuitive style like the first one, but internal I would do transformations so the data could be continuous in memory, and I would achieve more performance.

Is there any way of doing this so it could accept any class with the first type of struct and be able to convert it to the second approach? (or is any tool that is able to do this type of transformation).

Comment: I do that a lot, but always do it by hand. It would be interesting to hear what the others say. (+1)

Comment: There is no way to do this, but why do you think it will be faster to a degree that affects performance?

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Better locality of reference and more compact representation. I've profiled this sort of stuff quite a lot, and in many cases there's no contest.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way to ensure better locality, but I'd guess the JVM would allocate them close together if they are instantiated one after another. If they are being created and GC'd constanty then you may have issues.

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to optimize for? You would only save one dereference (AFAICT)

Comment: Java doesn't really have structs in the way it looks like the OP expects; that's basically a limitation of Java, albeit not a terrible one.

Comment: @NPE I don't understand memory access much but does it not depend on how the objects are being used? For example, if all fields are accessed in each iterations does it still help to organize as above?

Comment: @MiserableVariable I had some algorithm (although it was in c) that changing from AoP to SoA I had gain almost 1.5 in speedup.

Comment: For the example I had give, if you have a function that is accessing a lot only to the elements of array a, with the second approach I can have a unit stride of 1 while this will not happen with the first one.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Locality is important in a lot of not-so-obvious ways, e.g. caching - when you make a read to a bit of memory, the computer will cache the memory around it in the hopes that you'll need it as well. Accessing all of the variables each time will mean the top level cache(s) might be dropped, but lower level ones can still work nicely.

Comment: Two problems with this approach: 1) Arrays are special to the JVM, and unless you have a way to hook either the Java compiler (which usually translates this 1:1 to JVM arrays) or the JVM (can AspectJ do that? wat.), arrays remain special to the JVM. Perhaps a preprocessor might do what you want, or as you mention, reflection (again: wat.). 2) If you were to solve this problem, you've introduced a crack in the (already wonky) semantics of Java. What would `public X array_of_x[SIZE1][SIZE2]` mean, for instance?

Comment: @Tinctorius yep you are right, it not easy at all, I would have to restrict with primitive array in the beginning. An still I would probably need a pre processor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's create an interface that exhibits the first layout for usage, and an implementation for that interface that uses the second layout internally. (Access modifiers stripped from the code.)

```
interface X {
    double getA();
    double getB();
    double getC();
};

interface ArrayOfX {
    X get(int index);
};

class ContiguousArrayOfX implements ArrayOfX {
    class ContiguousX implements X {
        int index;
        ContiguousX(int index) {
            this.index = index; }
        double getA() { return a[index]; }
        double getB() { return b[index]; }
        double getC() { return c[index]; }
    }

    X get(int index) {
        return new ContiguousX(index); }

    double a[] = new double [SIZE];
    double b[] = new double [SIZE];
    double c[] = new double [SIZE];
};
```

If you want to lessen the burden on the GC, you can also cache all instances of `ContiguousX`. It depends pretty much on the aptitude of the JIT compiler if the `ContiguousX` objects are allocated on the heap at all -- they might well live in the stack, in this case the overhead is negligible. As a last resort, you can define an alternative interface for fast access:

```
interface FasterArrayOfX {
    double getA(int index);
    double getB(int index);
    double getC(int index);
};

class FasterContiguousArrayOfX extends ContiguousArrayOfX implements FasterArrayOfX {
   // Exercise left to the reader
};
```

By programming against an interface you are always free to choose the storage later on.

It is rather straightforward to write a code generator for any given class layout. The code above can be used as boilerplate, only the method and array declarations are dependent on the class layout you want to obtain. I am not aware of any existing tool.